# How to Disable the visualization of Injected Environment variables in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins SECURITY-248 states that I should "Disable the visualization of Injected Environment variables in the global configuration." I cannot find this setting in the Configuration. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do the following to make sure to address this security issue correctly:

1. Check to see if you have any files affected by this security issue by executing this command:  `sudo find . -name "injectedEnvVars.txt"`
2. Delete all the files recursively by executing the following command:  `sudo find . -name "injectedEnvVars.txt" -delete`
3. Re-execute step #1 to make sure there are no files left.
4. Go to the Jenkins instance, from `Configure Global Security` under `Environment Injector Plugin` check `Do not show injected variables`.
   [image: Prevent the plugin from leaking secrets again]
5. From `Configure Global Security` under `Hidden security warnings`, click on `Security Warnings` and then uncheck `Environment Injector Plugin: Exposure of sensitive build variables stored by EnvInject 1.90 and earlier`. This will make sure to hide that error message so it doesn’t appear again.
   [image: Prevent the warning message from showing #1]
   [image: Prevent the warning message from showing #2]

**Reference:** https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2018-02-26/#SECURITY-248

Comment: Any risk to deleting all of these files? I am assuming later versions of the Environment Inject plugin no longer needs these files so they are no longer needed?

Comment: @hvaughan3 There is no risk in deleting those files. They were exposed unnecessarily which was a security risk. After fixing the issue by the plugin developers, you still need to delete the old files to prevent access to your passwords.

Comment: Just to note, if anywhere, these files will be stored with your job builds (e.g. /path/to/jenkins/jobs/) just to limit your search scope.

Answer (score 3):

Configure Global Security
{buildhost}/configureSecurity/

at the bottom is "Do not show injected variables"

Comment: Unfortunately I still get following message:
Environment Injector Plugin 2.1.5
Exposure of sensitive build variables stored by EnvInject 1.90 and earlier

Comment: yeah, I just hid it after changing that setting. I don't think it checks current state, just that there was a problem with the given plugin