# Jenkins groovy setup for security warnings

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

[How to Disable the visualization of Injected Environment variables in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296119/how-to-disable-the-visualization-of-injected-environment-variables-in-jenkins)

to solve Jenkins security alert - https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2018-02-26/#SECURITY-248

I update my groovy setup script with

```
import jenkins.model.*;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.*

EnvInjectPluginConfiguration envInject = GlobalConfiguration.all().get(EnvInjectPluginConfiguration.class)
envInject.setHideInjectedVars(true)
```

I couldn't find a way to set the second part of the solution **Go to the Jenkins instance, from Configure Global Security under Environment Injector Plugin check Do not show injected variables.**  via groovy

any idea how to make it work

Comment: Sure you are checking in the correct place? I have taken a look on our Jenkins and found it quite quickly https://<jenkins_url>/configureSecurity/ and found a section called Environment Injector Plugin

Comment: I find this one , wanted that my groovy script will update this value.

Answer (score 3):

here is the groovy script to setup this issue

```
import jenkins.model.*;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.*

EnvInjectPluginConfiguration envInject = GlobalConfiguration.all().get(EnvInjectPluginConfiguration.class)
envInject.setHideInjectedVars(true)

// update warnings
import jenkins.security.*

ExtensionList<UpdateSiteWarningsConfiguration> configurations = ExtensionList.lookup(UpdateSiteWarningsConfiguration.class);
println configurations

UpdateSiteWarningsConfiguration configuration = configurations.get(0);
HashSet<UpdateSite.Warning> activeWarnings = new HashSet<>();

activeWarnings.add('SECURITY-248')

configuration.ignoredWarnings = activeWarnings

configuration.save()
```